# how to get cookie php/wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, setcookie

Users come to my site thorough a referral link.

I can successfully set the cookie using either of the following code snippets:
(I know it is successful because I can see the cookie file saved on my computer)

```
function set_my_cookie() { 
if (empty($_COOKIE['OREF2']))
{
wp_set_auth_cookie('OREF2', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], time()+5200, "/", ".website.com");
}
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_my_cookie');
```

or

```
function set_newuser_cookie() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['OREF2'])) {
        setcookie('OREF2', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], time()+5200, "/", ".website.com");
}
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_newuser_cookie');
```

Now the user clicks to a different page in my site. They click a form which should pass the cookie info when they click submit.

I am using the following code snippets:

```
function get_my_cookie() { 
//$_COOKIE['OREF2'];
//var_dump($_COOKIE);
echo $_COOKIE['OREF2'];
}
add_shortcode('cookies', 'get_my_cookie');
```

This first bit of code has commented lines where I have attempted different ways to get my cookie. None of the 3 ways worked. I then moved on to trying to read if my cookie is set with the following code:

```
function get_my_cookie() { 
if(!isset($_COOKIE['OREF2'])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . OREF2 . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . OREF2 . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE['OREF2'];
}}
add_shortcode('cookies', 'get_my_cookie');
```

When using this code I am ALWAYS met with "cookie is NOT set" Even though I can clearly see the cookie file on my computer. If the cookie is not set my shortcode can't be used to display anything...

All I want is a shortcode to display my cookie. What am I doing wrong? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you still trying to use the https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie ?

Comment: I have used all combinations of my code listed here. No combination works. Currently I am using the "setcookie" code.

Comment: when you run `setcookie()`, what is the value it returns? I would also test by reducing to: `setcookie('OREF2', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], time()+5200);` Also clear the cookie from previous testing.

Comment: no matter what I've tried I am always met with "cookie is not set" I will try the reduced code now.

Comment: > Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling `print_r($_COOKIE);`.

Comment: Now it returns that is it is set using the reduced code. 
Cookie 'OREF2' is set!
Value is: REF=jujujuju

If the shortcode is on the Echo function, should my shortcode pass "REF=jujujuju"

Comment: I suspect something in your Folder or Domain setting is not right or does not match well. Will expand in answer.

Comment: I am coding this site in localhost. If I add a shortcode to just echo the cookie, it is not sending the info.

Comment: Posted an answer that I think will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the following code:

```
setcookie('OREF2', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], time()+5200, "/", ".website.com");
```

This may not setup the cookie properly. One test would be to clear the cookie and test with :

```
setcookie('OREF2', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], time()+5200);
```

These parameters, Path and Domain, are optional. If they are not set correctly, even slightly, you (actually the browser) will not be able to read the Cookie properly as the HTTP URL may not match properly.

As suggested in the comments, you may want to examine this more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

> Something that wasn't made clear to me here and totally confused me for a while was that domain names must contain at least two dots (.), hence 'localhost' is invalid and the browser will refuse to set the cookie! instead for localhost you should use false.
>
> To make your code work on both localhost and a proper domain, you can do this:
>
> `<?php`
>
> `$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;`
>
> `setcookie('cookiename', 'data', time()+60*60*24*365, '/', $domain, false);`
>
> `?>`

You may want to consider using this code going forward:

```
function set_newuser_cookie() {
  if (!isset($_COOKIE['OREF2'])) {
    $domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;
    setcookie('OREF2', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], time()+5200, "/", $domain);
  }
}
```

Comment: Using your code example: would my function output the cookie from a shortcode? --function get_my_cookie() { 
//$_COOKIE['OREF2'];
//var_dump($_COOKIE);
echo $_COOKIE['OREF2'];
}
add_shortcode('cookies', 'get_my_cookie');

Comment: Using your code example I am back to getting the echo " cookie is NOT set.

Comment: This would suggest there is still something strange with your Path or Domain. If your test is still not finding the cookie, something about it's setup is different. Please edit your post and include more details: Browser version, what do you see exactly (screen shot maybe) of your cookie details in the browser. Does your browsers console have any alerts or errors?

Answer (score 0):

User comes to site through referral source-cookie is created from query string.

```
function set_my_cookie() { 
if (empty($_COOKIE['OREF2']))
{
wp_set_auth_cookie('OREF2', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], time()+5200);
}
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_my_cookie');
```

Now the user clicks to a different page in site. They click a form which should pass the cookie info through a shortcode when they click submit.

```
function get_my_cookie() { 
return $_COOKIE['OREF2'];
}
add_shortcode('cookies', 'get_my_cookie');
```

This now sets the cookie, and allows the shortcode "cookies" to retrieve the stored cookie value at any time.

Thanks to twisty for helping me with the reduced set cookie code and explaining the domain path.

This works on localhost no problem!

:)