# How to use session without using $_SESSION in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I am trying to create a session without using php `$_SESSION` variable and without letting user to log in on the website. I created a form and once a visitor/guest user submit the form, I want to store his data in a session variable. I found that using `$_SESSION` is not a good practice in wordpress. I looked around some tutorials and found to use `WP_Session`. This also seems not working for me.

Here is the code I am using:

```
global $wp_session;
$wp_session['visitorInfo'] = 'some_text_here';
```

When I am requesting it on another page it gives me nothing(blank). Even if I try to print `$wp_session` variable, it also give me blank. I also tried with `$wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();`, but it returns me error that `Class WP_Session not found` may be because I am using namespace for the class in which I am calling this method.

I also tried to

```
add_action('init',array($this,'start_session'));
public function start_session(){
  if (!session_id()) { session_start();}
}
```

but its not working.

My website is hosted on wpengine and it doesn't allow creating custom cookies. I am trying to figure out how wordpress create their session when user login to the website. I have been looking for the solution from last 2 days but didn't found any working solution.

Can you please suggest me how I can achieve this.

Many many thank in advance!

Comment: Use `init` hook and check with `session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE` before `session_start()` work for me. If it isn't work for you, what is the error details?

Comment: The `WP_Session` class is from [WP Session manager plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/). It is not WordPress core class. So, you need to have this plugin to access this class.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70696422/php-active-session-warning-in-wordpress/70697085#70697085

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `init` hook to `session_start()` is working fine on normal server without WP Engine.

Example code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Session plugin.
 */


add_action('init', 'sesp_init');
function sesp_init()
{
    if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }
    $_SESSION['hello'] = 'world';

    // maybe un-comment the line below if WordPress site health alert about active session.
    //session_write_close();
}


add_action('template_redirect', 'sesp_template');
function sesp_template()
{
    echo 'hello ' . $_SESSION['hello'].'<br>';
}
```

It say *hello world* on the front pages.

However, you may need to add `session_write_close()` after set `$_SESSION` value due to WordPress site health may alert "*An active PHP session was detected*".

#### `WP_Session`

The class `WP_Session` is not WordPress core class. I couldn't find this class anywhere in WordPress core files except [`WP_Session_Token`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_session_tokens/) but that is not for session usage.

The class `WP_Session` is from [WP Session Manager plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/) (refer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811748/how-do-you-use-session-variables-in-wordpress/23811817)). You have to install that plugin to access `WP_Session`. Otherwise this error will be occur.

> Class WP_Session not found

#### Use [Transients](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/).

From the document.

> WordPress Transients API, which offers a simple and standardized way of storing cached data in the database temporarily

So, you can use it as alternative if `session_start()` is not really work and you don't want to install other plugin.

Example code:

```
add_action('init', 'sesp_init');
function sesp_init()
{
    set_transient('sesp_hello', 'moon', 60*5);// 5 minutes.
}


add_action('template_redirect', 'sesp_template');
function sesp_template()
{
    echo 'hello ' . get_transient('sesp_hello') . ' (use transient).<br>';
}
```

You don't need to hook into `init` to set transient. The code above is for example. The third argument in `set_transient()` is expiration in seconds.

##### Transient Warning!

However, the transient is not for one visitor like the session. You have to set and check properly that the transient you are getting and setting is match for a person.

#### WP Engine

From their [support page](https://wpengine.com/support/cookies-and-php-sessions/).

> The biggest problem this presents is due to the unique session IDs. Unique IDs effectively bust cache and causes every session to become uncached. This will cause serious performance issues for your site.

You may switch to use PHP [cookie](https://wpengine.com/resources/wordpress-cookies/) or disable WP Engine cache. This was [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51806561/128761).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. It cleared everything and gave me a direction. Now  I am using PHP cookie to achieve the goal. It works fine. Just want to confirm that will there be any case PHP Cookie will not work?

Comment: @DevD From many questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659257/how-to-get-cookie-php-wordpress), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183162/how-can-i-set-get-and-destroy-cookies-in-wordpress), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788355/how-to-set-a-cookie-in-wordpress). They use normal read and write cookie as normal PHP did. You may need to research more about cookie constant by WordPress that will be useful.